# Git is not picking up my changed files

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm trying to create a new branch which contains a different version of my project. Unfortunately the newer version's files, while they have different contents, don't get noticed by git as changed and can't be committed.

The folder\files are nearly identical and were placed into the directory at the same time from a backup. The contents of some files are different and I need these changes reflected in a new branch.

By way of example, take this simple mockup I've tried using 2 text files.

File structure:

```
project/
├── older/
│   ├── File 1.txt
│   ├── File 2.txt
├── newer/
│   ├── File 1.txt
│   └── File 2.txt
```

Structure is similar for my actual project, just with a lot more files and subfolders.

```
Mr JF@Computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/testproject (master)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Mr JF@Computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/testproject (master)
$ stat -c "%y %s %n" *
2018-03-15 15:43:35.764654900 +0000 15 File 1.txt
2018-03-15 15:43:35.765656300 +0000 17 file 2.txt

Mr JF@Computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/testproject (master)
$ git checkout -b newerbranch
Switched to branch 'newerbranch'
```

I copy the newer version of File 1 & 2.txt into the repository here, then:

```
Mr JF@Computer MINGW64 ~/Desktop/testproject (newerbranch)
$ git status
On branch newerbranch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

What's going on here?

Comment: If the newer files are already in a branch "newerbranch", it makes sense that no diff is noticed, as you havnt changed anything in context of that branch. What are you trying to do? Merge newer branch into master?

Comment: No the newer files don't exist in git yet, I have the files stored locally and am trying to just copy them into my repo and push them into a new branch.

Comment: If they’re new files, don’t you need to add them? `git add .`

Comment: Yes, but git add doesn't see anything to add.

Comment: Compared to your example file structure, which is the root of your Git repo? Is it `project/` or `older/`? And with your example `git status`, what differences do you expect to see? Do you expect to see untracked files or changed files?

Comment: Until you give more details there are many possible reasons, but one reason to consider is the [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) feature. If there are untracked files that were never committed, and there is a `.gitignore` file somewhere or a `core.excludesFile` setting that lists those files or one of their parent folders, then `git status` won't show those files and any changes to them.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Both are the root. They're essentially clones of each other but with some differences. The differences I'd expect to see are the code changes between files within older/newerbranch. gitignore is in place but isn't affecting .aspx or .cs files which are the ones i'm hoping it will track. They track fine if I manually make changes to the original files then try to see the status or add. If I just dump the contents of newerbranch into my repo, it ignores everything until I manually make a change. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Can you cat both the files and make sure you are getting the right files? Also can you execute `env` command and see if there are any variables set related to `GIT`

Comment: Not sure if I can use cat but I've opened the files in an editor and they are different. I use Git for windows so the commands are in the path within there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would try these things:

1. Make sure that the files are not ignored by running `git check-ignore -v path/to/file`
2. Run `git update-index --really-refresh` to refresh the index and ignore any files that may have been muted using `git update-index --assume-unchanged`

If indeed this is not a user error, I would assume the issue lies with the underlying filesystem and/or how Git interfaces with it.

Comment: Thanks, the `update-index --really-refresh` command seems to have done the trick.

Comment: #1 worked for me.  When you're working on a new project/framework stuff might be ignored for reasons you haven't learned about yet.

Answer (score 1):

So I developed this issue as well. It turns out that since you are certain the only file changes is the folder name. Just rename the working directory folder to something else. Git will pick the new change. Commit the new changes. Then you can rename it to the right name you want. Git will pick it up the changes again and then git has the updated folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The comment section isnt big enough for me to paste my own test so ill use this. If i were you i'd double check that the files you copied into the branch really are different. When i repeat your test it works fine:

```
test $ls
file1.txt file2.txt
test $git status
On branch newerbranch
nothing to commit, working tree clean
test $mkdir new
test $cd new
new $echo "new file1" > file1.txt
new $echo "new file2" > file2.txt
new $cd ..
test $rm file1.txt file2.txt
test $mv new/* .
test $rm -rf new/
test $git status
On branch newerbranch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file1.txt
    modified:   file2.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: Yes that's because you manually changed the file by echoing the change into it. I didn't - I have a clone of the folder with some changes already saved and I want to copy those to my repository folder and then commit them.

Comment: I edited my post to show what i see when i create new file1 and file2 and then copy them into my repository. Works as planned still. Sorry I couldnt help. Check your .gitignore as Rory mentioned, that could be it. Please update us if you figure it out, now im curious

Comment: Have you got a windows machine to try this on? Create a folder with some stuff in it, then make a copy of it via windows explorer rather than console commands. Push the first folder. Then paste in the contents of the copied folder and try git add/status and see if it picks them up

Comment: i dont have any windows machines. But anyhow in that process you just described, no changes would be found because simply copying the files into another folder doesn't constitute a change. The content of the files has to be changed, not just the file inodes.

Comment: The content is different though.